# VSTO word find with formatting

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I recently find interest in VSTO and now trying to build a word addon.

Basically I am trying to search all Italic text. But I could not find any help how to do this.

```
            Word.Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range;
            Word.Find searchRange = rng.Find;
            searchRange.ClearFormatting();
            searchRange.Format = true;

            searchRange.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            searchRange.Format = Font.Italic;

            object textToFind = "the";
            if (searchRange.Execute(ref textToFind, ref missing, ref missing, ref
            missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref
            missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found text: " + textToFind, "Finding...");
                rng.Font.Italic = 1;
                rng.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue;
            }
```

But there are many errors as it is not working.

My question is How to define the formatting for a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One basic/easy italic find would be with this:

```
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Find.Font.Italic = 9;
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Find.Font.Name = "Calibri";
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Find.Execute();
```